# Локальный файл конфигурации Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть основной файл, который содержит основные функции. Также есть файл конфигурации в котором пользователь может менять значение переменных. Вопрос в том как импортировать переменные js (все это должно работать **локально** - чистый html + javascript). Возможно ли это?

Comment: А где есть «файл конфигурации»? На компьютере пользователя?

Comment: @Alexey Ten Именно.

Comment: А как ваш JS будет читать этот файл? Обычно у сайтов нет доступа к файловой системе. Можно подробнее, откуда вообще берётся html/js?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого пригодится [JS Modules](https://learn.javascript.ru/modules)

В файле конфига делаешь

```
const config = {
  someVar: someVal
}
export default config;
```

А потом в основном `.js`

```
import config from './config'
```

`'./config'` означает то, что файл конфига находится в той же директории, что и скрипт, из которого ты его вызываешь. Название файла - `config.js`, но в `import` его можно не писать

Учти, что это работет только в новых браузерах. Чтобы работало кроссбраузерно (насколько это возможно), нужно использовать [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: в файле `config` нет экспорта по умолчанию

Comment: @overthesanity спасибо за уточнение. Исправил

Answer (score -1):

Для начала попробуй просто загрузить скрипт:

```js
// файл настоек выглядит так
var config = {
    //
}

// пишем загрузчик
function loadScript(url, callback){
    var script = document.createElement('script')
        script.src = url
        script.onload = callback
    document.body.appendChild(script)
}

// и загружаем
var loadedConfig
loadScript('config.js',function(){
    loadedConfig = window.config
})
```

Да, засоряется глобальная область видимости. В дальнейшем лучше json и xhr.

Answer (score -3):

Ну как то так

```js
// main.js

export {a, b} // Експортируем  переменные. Чтобы их можно было импортировать

var a = "Hello";

var b = false
```

```js
import {a, b} from "main" // Импортируем переменные 

console.log(a, b) // Выводим в консоль
```